# Search data by two variables, then sum associated values

Tags: excel, sum, pivot-table

I am working on a scheduling database that tracks the master schedule for all the classes, the student hours, and the hours teachers have worked. The problem I am running into is the final area of this workbook in Excel.

We want to show the teacher hours by each month (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc) and the name of the interpreter.

```
---------Jan---Feb---Mar---Apr---May---...
-Teach1
-Teach2
-Teach3
```

I want to pull this data from the master schedule which has three columns I will use:

```
---Date ---- Teacher Name --- Class Hours
 1/23/2013 -- Teach1-----------      1
10/10/2013 -- Teach2-----------      2
10/23/2013 -- Teach1-----------      4
10/23/2013 -- Teach1-----------      2
```

So, I am trying to pull a sum of the data for `Teach1` for October.

Comment: Look into the `Sumifs` function (http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx) using the month of the date as one criteria and the teacher name as the other.... Give it a try and then post back your attempts and we'll help you along

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a PivotTable as shown:

[image]

where the dates are formatted mmm and Grouped by month.